# CouchDB log does not work in map nor reduce function?

Tags: couchdb

The [doc](https://people.apache.org/~dch/snapshots/couchdb/20140715/new-docs-build/html/query-server/javascript.html#log) says there is a `log` method to write message to log file at INFO level.
I tried but it does not work. (CouchDB 1.6.1)

First I start monitoring the log file

```
tail -f couch.log
```

I see the log file is being appended and other INFO messages appear like.

```
[Tue, 06 Jan 2015 08:16:10 GMT] [info] [<0.321.0>] 192.168.1.43 - - GET /test/ 200
[Tue, 06 Jan 2015 08:16:10 GMT] [info] [<0.323.0>] 192.168.1.45 - - GET /test/ 200
```

I tried `log` in views (including temp view or persistence view), the message never appears while the other INFO messages are being appended. The view responses correctly. also tried to add new documents and then trigger the view, still nothing.

```
function(doc) {
  log('LOG NEVER APPEARS');
  emit(null, doc);
}
```

Does anybody know what the reason is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What probably happened was you created the view and the log function logged the request on the terminal. When you `tailed` it the index was already created and the view code was not run again. Try to add some data and call the view again. Or change the view->save it->call the view again and you should see the logged message.

This is happening because the view code is run only when the underlying data in couchdb changes. Once a view is created it grows by appending the new data to the already existing index. If the data is not changed the code inside the view will not be run.